# select columns have the same string in header of columns

Tags: shell

I have a data file with a lot of columns. It was generated from files with the same format. The header is like this:

```
gene    strand  coord   exression   SRR1234 gene    strand  coord   exression   SRR1235 gene    strand  coord   exression   SRR1236
```

I hope to extract "gene" and columns with "SRR*" in shell.

Does anyone have experience on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cols=$(head -n 1 datafilename | sed -e "s/\s\+/\n/g" | nl -w1 | grep 'SRR*\|gene' | cut -f 1)
cut -f"${cols//$'\n'/,}" datafilename
```

#### How?

First, we read just the first row with `head`, then we change the whitespace (tabs, in this case) to newlines with `sed`, then we print out the columns with numbers next to them with `nl`. It'll look like this:

```
1 gene
2 strand
...
```

After that, we display only the lines with the items you care about via `grep`, and then we keep only the first field with `cut`, leaving us just the number that was in front of the column names for the columns we want. Now we have a newline separated list of numbers that we care about, so we use parameter expansion to do substitution to change it to a comma separated list of numbers, and we pass that to `cut` to display only those columns.

Comment: @JunchengLin, if you click the green checkmark near the top left of my answer, you will "accept" the answer and let others know your question has been resolved.